# PostgreSQL Import CVS Issue

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When importing a cvs file into postgresql using pgadmin III, it says import successful and then I am able to hit done. However, when I look into the table -- no data is there. Has anyone experienced a similar issue ? I have imported in the past, with no change in environment, to success, but I do not know what is happening now

Comment: Any error message? What are the steps you are doing? Add some screenshots or describe it at least.

Comment: Well, that is the issue. I receive no error messages, I am just using import when right clicking on the table.

Comment: Did you check the file encoding and the table encoding? Are they match?

Comment: Yes,I used all procedures found on the pgadmin tutorial for importing. Headers, delimiters, etc.. everything is fine, and it imports, but the data does not show.

Comment: Is it possible that the table has any trigger that may be validating the data?

Comment: No, I have no trigger functions